# Redirect from nginx to wordpress with apache under other domain

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx

I have a project (www.xxx.com) running under nginx. In this project, I need point a subdirectory (www.xxx.com/blog) to a blog with Wordpress in other domain too under a folder (www.yyy.com/blog) under the Apache.

I changed my WP to run with permalinks and didn't configure the .htaccess. I made it on nginx with the following code:

```
location /blog {
 try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$request_uri;
 proxy_pass http://static.gri.fo/blog;
}
```

It makes a 500 Internal Server Error nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

In the log it returns:

2015/08/31 13:19:39 [error] 7565#0: *1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/blog/index.php", client: 179.219.42.26, server: www.xxx.com.br, request: "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.xxx.com.br"

Any idea to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear on what you're trying to do, but perhaps the following is what you're after?

```
location /blog {
    proxy_pass http://static.gri.fo/blog/index.php?q=$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run both `try_files` and `proxy_pass` in the same location block and as mentioned by another, your question is not particularly clear on what you are trying to do.

## Possibility 1:

Trying to simply serve incoming requests to **`www.xxx.com/blog`** from **`www.yyy.com/blog`**

```
location /blog {
    proxy_pass http://yyy.com/blog;
}
```

## Possibility 2:

Trying to serve incoming requests to **`www.xxx.com/blog`** from **`www.yyy.com/blog`** if the file is not found in **`www.xxx.com/blog`**
This is how you combine `try_files` and `proxy_pass`
You separate out the `proxy_pass` into a named location block and call that from the `try_files` directive

```
location /blog {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
}
location @proxy {
    proxy_pass http://yyy.com/blog;
}
```